# Difference between ( ) & and ( &)?

Tags: bash, subshell

I'm wondering what's the difference between these two grammar in bash: `(   &)` and `(    ) &`.

The only difference that I noticed is, `(tty &)` will return "not a tty" while `(tty) &` will return the current tty name, but why?

To give an example, should I run `(setsid startx &)` or `(setsid startx) &`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the case of

```
(tty &)
```

a subshell is started which starts another `tty` process in the background without job control and terminal, hence there is a "not a tty" error. The `tty` process becomes detached with PPID 1

In the case of

```
(tty) &
```

a subshell is started and runs in the background. This background shell starts a `tty` process and after tty finishes and reports to the terminal, the subshell finishes in the background.

--

`tty` is a simple command. Whether or not a particular command (like `startx`) needs a `( ... &)` construct to become detached / disowned from a parent process depends on the command itself. There are a number of ways for a process to in turn start a subprocess and detach that, so the command may not need it.

Comment: If `X &` runs X without a controlling terminal, it seems `(tty)&` would run the subshell without a controlling terminal, and therefore the `tty` command wouldn't have a controlling terminal either.  Is the difference due to whether the background process is started by the session leader?

Comment: @VaughnCato There are a number of ways for a process to in turn start a subprocess and detach it. It also matters if a command is executed from an interactive shells or not. `(tty)&` will not run without a controlling terminal if it is executed from an interactive shell. You can easily test this by replacing `tty` with `sleep 60` for example and checking with `ps`.